# C++ no matching function for call to error

Tags: c++, class, object, c++11

I am trying to simulate a certain game as an exercise (dont ask me which, you will know if you know the game), however, I just learnt objects and class on the internet and the whole thing is still so confusing to me. The following is a section of my code that is giving me an error.

The error I have is:

```
C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    In constructor 'ekop::Moveset::Moveset()':
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no matching function for call to 'Move::Move()'
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidates are:
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(std::string, int, int, int)
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(const Move&)
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no matching function for call to 'Move::Move()'
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidates are:
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(std::string, int, int, int)
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(const Move&)
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no matching function for call to 'Move::Move()'
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidates are:
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(std::string, int, int, int)
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(const Move&)
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no matching function for call to 'Move::Move()'
56  9   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidates are:
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(std::string, int, int, int)
14  3   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] Move::Move(const Move&)
11  7   C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    In constructor 'ekop::ekop()':
52  12  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Note] synthesized method 'ekop::Moveset::Moveset()' first required here
```

I don't know what went wrong, the code is below.
Don't tell me not to use `using namespace std;`, I know I am not supposed to do that but I am not going to fix that in this program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h> /* time */
using namespace std;

class Move
{
    public:
        Move(string a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            name = a;
            type_num = b;
            power = c;
            accuracy = d;
        }

        void setName (string a)
        {
            name = a;
        }

        void setType_num(int a)
        {
            type_num = a;
        }

        void setPower(int a)
        {
            power = a;
        }

        void setAccuracy(int a)
        {
            accuracy = a;
        }

    private:
        string name, type;
        int type_num, power, accuracy;
};

class ekop
{
    public:
        ekop()
        {
            Moveset moveset;
        }

    private:
        class Moveset
        {
            public:
                //constructor
                //retrievors
            private:
                Move slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4;
        };
};

int main()
{
    //lines of code
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

edit 1: I had this constructor for the class Moveset, but since it didnt affect the error when I took it out, so I didnt include that in the post just now.

```
Moveset()
                {
                    slot1.setName("MOVE 1");
                    slot1.setType_num(rand()%18);
                    slot1.setPower(10*(rand%15+1));
                    slot1.setAccuracy(5*(rand%11+10));
                    //repeat for the rest of the slots
                }
```

edit 2:
Now if I do this instead:

```
        //No change before this
        class Moveset
        {
            public:
                //constructor
                //retrievors
            private:
                Move slot1("MOVE 1", rand() % 18, 10*(rand % 15 + 1), 5 * (rand % 11 + 10)),
                     slot2("MOVE 2", rand() % 18, 10*(rand % 15 + 1), 5 * (rand % 11 + 10)), 
                     slot3("MOVE 3", rand() % 18, 10*(rand % 15 + 1), 5 * (rand % 11 + 10)),
                     slot4("MOVE 4", rand() % 18, 10*(rand % 15 + 1), 5 * (rand % 11 + 10));
        };
};

//no change after this
```

I get this error instead:

```
62  16  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected identifier before string constant
62  16  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected ',' or '...' before string constant
63  16  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected identifier before string constant
63  16  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected ',' or '...' before string constant
64  13  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected identifier before string constant
64  13  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected ',' or '...' before string constant
65  13  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected identifier before string constant
65  13  C:\Users\N\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected ',' or '...' before string constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you've got no *default constructor* for Move. To make this code work, add the following to the public section of the Move class:

```
Move() {
    //Give fields default values here
}
```

When you declare a variable without initializing it, it calls the default constructor (the constructor with no arguments) to give the variable default values until it's used. Sometimes these default values are kept, sometimes you assign a new object to it.. But that's depends on what you want to do and isn't really relevant.

Edit: Okay so to elaborate, there are a couple of ways to declare/initialize variables in C++. I'll use std::string as an example, but this applies to any type (even the fundamental types, though their classes aren't defined, per se, as much as just built into the language):

```
std::string str1;
std::string str2 = "Two";
std::string str3("Three");
std::string str4 = std::string("Four");
```

`str1` is just a declaration, the rest are declarations *and* initializations (they declare the variable, and then give it an initial value).

`str1` calls the default constructor, because no initial value is provided. Therefore, the compiler needs *something* to assign to `str1` and the default constructor provides that something.

`str2` and `str3` are actually different styles of the exact same call - a call to one of the parameterized `std::string` constructors (namely, in this case, the `std::string(const char*)` constructor). `str3` is fairly self explanatory: its like a normal function call, only it's the constructor being called, not a normal function. `str2` shows a funny thing about C++ - when initializing a variable with the `=` sign, it calls a constructor. In this case, is calls a *converting constructor*, which I'll go into a little more detail about, but I'll wait till the end.

Finally, `str4`, unlike the others, actually calls *two* constructors (making it the least efficient, technically speaking). The first one called is the `std::string("Four")`, which creates an unnamed `std::string` object, which is *then* passed to the `std::string` *copy constructor* (which looks like `std::string(std::string&)`) to create the `str4` variable.

It goes like this: an unnamed `std::string` object is created and given the value "Four" (`std::string("Four")`). That object is then passed (by that quirky `=` sign again) to the `std::string` copy constructor, to copy the unnamed string object to `str4`, completing it's creation. See that this method calls two constructors, creating an extra unnecessary object that's used in the creation of `str4`.

Now - *converting constructors*. If a class defines a constructor that takes a single parameter, that constructor is a converting constructor. So basically, whenever an object of that class is initialized with a value that can be taken by a converting constructor, that value is passed to the constructor and the constructor handles it from there.

Converting constructors aren't anything special - they're just normal constructors. The only difference is that you don't need parentheses to call it when initializing, you just put the value there. Take the `std::string(const char*)` constructor. This constructor acts to convert `const char*` (known as a C-style string, from the days of the C language) to a `std::string` object. With a converting constructor, you can put the parameter value (e.g. const char*) anywhere that a `std::string` is required (in the return value of a function, for example) and it will automatically create a `std::string` object from the `const char*` (in case you didn't know, whenever you type something like `"Hello World"` it is actually a `const char*` value, though is it often converted to a `std::string` by your code).

One way you can avoid creating a converting constructor while still having one argument (because automatic - a.k.a implicit - conversions can sometimes be annoying) is to put the keyword `explicit` in front of the constructor declaration, which will tell the compilation not to do implicit conversions - meaning that whenever you want to convert, you must use `std::string("Hello World")` rather than just `"Hello World"`.

Hopefully you understand that I'm talking about, if not just let me know! By the way, I still need to verify what I've said about that `=` sign, which I'll use the Visual Studio debugger to do when I get home. I will update the post to reflect my findings.

Comment: I had a constructor but i didnt include that in this post. I will update the post to include it.
The reason I did not include it is because after I took it out it still gave me the same error so i thought it would be irrelevant to the problem i am facing now

Comment: I was actually talking about a *default* constructor, which is needed in this instance. Did you have one of those?

Comment: what is a default constructor?
sorry I am new to this

Comment: @nayfaan All good, everyone goes through this haha :) a default constructor is a constructor with no arguments. This is used when just declaring a variable (or property of a class). I'll add more details in my answer for you. Cheers' answer explains things pretty well.

Comment: i see so if i have a default constructor and another constructor with parameters, when I initialize without parameters, it uses the default constructor, but if I gave it parameters, it would get the default instead?

Comment: Yep - that's exactly how it works! To be honest I did have a big edit typed out on my phone and it's gone now, but if you'd like me to elaborate more on constructors and assigning variables I'll do so when I get home - just let me know.

Comment: I've edited the post to include my elaboration. I do need to verify some of the things I've said, which I can do later.

Answer (score 3):

A `MoveSet` contains four default-initialized `Move` instances, but `Move` has no default constructor – because you have defined a constructor, which suppresses automatic generation of a default constructor.

Since the class needs a user-defined default constructor (built in type data members will otherwise have arbitrary values), define one.

One way to define it is to provide default values for all arguments of the existing constructor, but I'd define a separate default constructor.

---

In passing, the existing code

```
Move(string a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    name = a;
    type_num = b;
    power = c;
    accuracy = d;
}
```

… which uses assignments to initialize members, has a problem as a general way to do this. Namely, that members of class type that can't be default-initialized, can't be initialized this way. You'd experience the same problem as above, namely error messages about lacking a default constructor.

A solution is to use a **member initializer list**, like this:

```
Move( string a, int b, int c, int d )
    : name( a ), type_num( b ), power( c ), accuracy( d )
{}
```

There are further possible refinements, such as `move` for efficiency or `const` for clarity (unfortunately one has to choose between them), but the important thing is to just generally adopt this convention of using member initializer lists, which works much more generally than assignments to members.

Comment: Sorry for the many edits correcting silly things, I'm just out of bed & decided to answer this before getting the all important cup of coffee.

Comment: This is a better answer. I wasn't actually aware that defining a non-default constructor suppressed the automatic generation of a default one :)

Comment: I am still so confused... the problem is I am not sure what is confusing me but I will try to ask...
so does it mean since i defined a constructor for Move, but when I created a Move object under Moveset I didnt input the parameters?

Comment: @nayfaan: Yes, that's an alternative way to fix things, to provide parameters to each `Move` object member in a `Moveset` constructor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did that in the second edit in the post about but that returned me another error?

Comment: @nayfaan: A simple way to do it is to define a `Moveset` constructor where you use a member initialization list to initialize the four `Move` data members. Alternatively you can keep the approach of providing the arguments directly in each declaration, but then (yeah it's pretty arbitrary) you have to use curly braces, like `slot1{ "blah", 1, 2, 3 }`. But all this is unnecessary if you just define a default constructor for `Move`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf curly braces？ i thought just use normal parentheses?

Comment: @nayfaan: The reasons are historical. In-place initialization of data members was not supported until C++11. Then it had to be force-fitted to the language, and to avoid some nasty notational clashes only two syntaxes were supported: curly braces, and `=` copy initialization.

Comment: so
`constructor (int a)
{
variable = a;
}`
is equal to
`constructor (int a)
:variable(a)
{}`

and
`Move(string a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    name = a;
    type_num = b;
    power = c;
    accuracy = d;
}`
can be done by
`Move(string a, int b, int c, int d)
object{"a", b, c, d}
{}`

? Is this syntax right?

Comment: I don't see where the `object` in that comes from. But, to learn about these things you need a textbook (as well as trying things out). Check out the [C++ Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here at SO. Unfortunately a moderator decided that it was non-SO-like and locked it down after editing it himself; it was a community effort. But it's still a good resource, compared to nothing.